# NSOpenGLView subclass crash in _enableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsopenglview

Updated: the crash doesn't occur on Sierra 10.12.6. But it does occur every time on my High Sierra  10.13.4 machie. So it seems like an AppKit issue introduced sometime in High Sierra. Logged a bug with Apple.

---

I have created a minimal example [here](https://github.com/thenextman/glsubclass_crash).

My `NSWindowController` loads it's `NSWindow` from a .xib file. The window only contains an `NSScrollView`. In `awakeFromNib`, I set the scroll view document to an instance of my `NSOpenGLView` subclass:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    sessionView = [[SessionView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1024, 768) pixelFormat:[NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat]];
    [self.sessionScrollView setDocumentView:sessionView];
}
```

The `NSOpenGLView` subclass can be completely empty implementation, e.g.:

*Header*

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>

@interface SessionView : NSOpenGLView
{

}

@end
```

*Imlementation*

```
#import "SessionView.h"

@implementation SessionView

@end
```

Now grab the corner of the window and start resizing. Keep your finger on the mouse button, drag the edge of the window around until it crash.

[Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaOvI.jpg)

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unbalanced needs display
>   in rect posting count.'

(I put the full stack trace at the end of the post, you will see that it is all framework code).

So something is happening in these methods `_enableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications` and `_enableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications`. Let's override them:

```
static int count;

- (void)_enableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications
{
    count--;

    NSLog(@"enable");
    [super _enableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications];
}

- (void)_disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications
{
    count++;

    NSLog(@"disable");
    [super _disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications];
}
```

We can see that while we are resizing the window, `_enableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications` is called repeatedly. Once we let go the mouse and end the resize, `_disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications` is called once for every time that `_enable...` was called.

The problem is, that if we hit a count of -63; we crash.

I can workaround by overriding these methods and not calling `super`.

What is going on?

Complete stack trace:

> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff504d932b
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 171 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff77b53c76 objc_exception_throw + 48 2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff504df0c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98 3
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff525fb340
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193 4
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff4e2a9af2
>   -[NSView(NSInternal) _disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications] + 190 5   test2                               0x000000010949ffb3 -[SessionView
>   _disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications] + 83 6   AppKit                              0x00007fff4e06876b -[_NSPortalView2 setSourceView:] + 166 7   AppKit
>   0x00007fff4e06802a -[NSPortalView dealloc] + 89 8   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff77b49087 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 817
>   9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff50412a56
>   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 22 10  Foundation                          0x00007fff525378ad -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 144 11  AppKit
>   0x00007fff4d9e3990 -[NSApplication run] + 1031 12  AppKit
>   0x00007fff4d9b2a72 NSApplicationMain + 804 13  test2
>   0x000000010949ffe2 main + 34 14  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff7876d015 start + 1 15  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff788bdb6e __pthread_kill + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff78a88080 pthread_kill +
>   333 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff788191ae abort + 127
>   3   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00007fff7671df8f abort_message +
>   245 4   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00007fff7671e12b
>   default_terminate_handler() + 265 5   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x00007fff77b55ea3 _objc_terminate() + 97 6   libc++abi.dylib
>     0x00007fff767397c9 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8 7
>
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00007fff7673926f __cxa_throw + 121 8 
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff77b53da5 objc_exception_throw
>   + 351 9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff504df0c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98 10  com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff525fb340 -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193 11 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff4e2a9af2 -[NSView(NSInternal)
>   _disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications] + 190 12  dev.test2                      0x000000010949ffb3 -[SessionView
>   _disableNeedsDisplayInRectNotifications] + 83 (SessionView.m:21) 13  com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff4e06876b -[_NSPortalView2
>   setSourceView:] + 166 14  com.apple.AppKit
>
>     0x00007fff4e06802a -[NSPortalView dealloc] + 89 15  libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x00007fff77b49087 (anonymous
>   namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 817 16 
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff50412a56
>   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 22 17  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff525378ad -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 144 18 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff4d9e3990 -[NSApplication run]
>   + 1031 19  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff4d9b2a72 NSApplicationMain + 804 20  dev.test2
>     0x000000010949ffe2 main + 34 (main.m:4) 21  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00007fff7876d015 start + 1

Comment: Please add the call stack as code, not as quote.

Comment: This is happening with `NSCollectionView` for me--ever figure this out?

Comment: I opened a radar with Apple, and they are asking me to confirm if it's fixed or not in 10.14. I haven't had to time to check yet; but my workaround has been working fine in production for the last several months.

Comment: @andyvn22 it appears to be fixed in the 10.14 beta